# ReferenceError: TransformStream is not defined

Tags: javascript, stream, jestjs, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I'm attempting to test the implementation of [Fast Google Fonts with Cloudflare Workers](https://blog.cloudflare.com/fast-google-fonts-with-cloudflare-workers/), from Cloudflare's blog for inlining the Google Fonts stylesheet directly into the HTML. The implementation itself seems to be working fine when running via the Cloudflare worker. But I wrote some tests, and when running the tests, I get this error that says `TransformStream` is not defined.

Error when running my Jest test via `npm run test`:

```
ReferenceError: TransformStream is not defined
```

This is the code that the test is hitting:

```
async function processHtmlResponse(request, response) {
  ...

  // This is where the reference error comes up 
  const { readable, writable } = new TransformStream();

  const newResponse = new Response(readable, response);
  modifyHtmlStream(response.body, writable, request, embedStylesheet);

  return newResponse;
}
```

This test looks something like this, where we basically expect that the stylesheet link will be replaced by the stylesheet itself, containing all the `@font-face` styles.

```
describe('inlineGoogleFontsHtml', () => {
  it('inlines the response of a Google Fonts stylesheet link within an HTML response', async () => {
    const request = new Request('https://example.com')
    const response = new Response(
        '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300"></head><body></body></html>',
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
          }
        }
    )
    const rewrittenResponse = processHtmlResponse(request, response)
    const rewrittenResponseText = await rewrittenResponse.text()
    expect(rewrittenResponseText).toContain('@font-face')
})
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is here. Does `TransformStream` work in Node? Is there some polyfill that's needed?

Related: 
[Cloudflare streams](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/apis/streams/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransformStream` is part of the [Streams API](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/), a browser-side standard. It is not implemented by Node (because they had their own streams long before this spec existed), so you will need a polyfill when testing your code in Node.

Incidentally, the example you're following is fairly old. These days, it would be better to use [HTMLRewriter](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/apis/html-rewriter/) to implement this kind of transformation -- it is much more efficient for rewriting HTML specifically. (However, it is a Cloudflare-specific feature, so you wouldn't be able to test it under Node at all.)

Comment: Ohh, got it. Thanks so much! Had a couple of questions regarding the HTMLRewriter.
What did you mean by this kind of transformation? Are there other types of transformations in which the HTMLRewriter would be less efficient compare to something like using a Regex.

Also, would you happen to know if there were any plans for something like the HTMLRewriter for JSON (e.g. to add keys at a certain place in a tree or to modify values)?

Comment: I mean if you're trying to transform HTML, then HTMLRewriter is the way to go. If it's some other format, you might be stuck with streams, or loading the whole thing into memory at once. For JSON the best bet is usually to parse it, modify the parsed version, and re-serialize -- but this may perform badly if the JSON is very large.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are running code on node which requires TransformStream object, it didn't work for me on v14.20, but seems to work on version 18, i.e. this can be checked via `node --version`